# show that $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}2^i\cdot i^{p-2}\equiv \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}i^{p-2}\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

let $p$ be odd prime number, show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}2^i\cdot i^{p-2}\equiv \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}i^{p-2}\pmod p$$

I know use this
$$i^{p-2}\equiv\dfrac{1}{i}\pmod p$$so
$$LHS\equiv \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\dfrac{2^i}{i}\pmod p$$
Then I can't prove it

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1198227p5878339

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}2^ii^{p-2}\equiv\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{2^i}{i}\equiv\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{i-1}2^i\binom{p}{i}=2-2^p \pmod{p^2}$$
And
$$\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}i^{p-2}\equiv\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{i}\equiv-\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i}\equiv-\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i}=2-2^p \pmod{p^2}$$